# Customize AdColony V4VC Popup Menu in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, adcolony

I'm adding V4VC ads from AdColony into my game and trying to change the default popup window.

Right now, it says:
 "Watch a sponsored video to earn 1 Coin?"

I need it to say:
 "Watch a sponsored video to earn 25 Diamonds?"

I looked on their support page and followed their instructions for setting up the app and currency on my account. However, the required code was in Objective-C. I need to convert this or find the correct code for V4VC ads in Swift:

```
NSString*currencyName=[AdColonygetVirtualCurrencyNameForZone:/*zoneID*/]; intcurrencyAmount=[AdColonygetVirtualCurrencyRewardAmountForZone:/*zoneID*/]; intremaining=[AdColonyPublicgetVideosPerReward:currencyName]‐[AdColonyPublicgetVideoCreditBalance:currencyName];
```

I am also using Sprite Kit. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log into our dashboard at https://clients.adcolony.com/ you can update the settings for your zone to show the name of your in game currency and the proper amount to award.

If you do have questions on this set up, email support@adcolony.com for more help on this process.